# Automapper ConstructUsing and Profile

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I'm using Automapper with dependency injection, so I've some mappers using AutoMapper.Profile
I'll show a simplified example of my issue:

```cs
 public class FlavorProfile : Profile
 {
    public FlavorProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FlavorEntity, FlavorDto>();
    }
 }
```

Now I want to map a class using a particular function:

```cs
 public class FruitDto
 {
    protected FruitDto() { }
    public static FruitDto Create(int Id,
                                  FlavorDto flavor)
    {
        // ..
        return fruit;
    }
 }
```

The Profile:

```cs
public class FruitProfile : Profile 
{
    public FruitProfile ()
    {
        CreateMap<FruitEntity, FruitDto>()
            .ConstructUsing(x => FruitDto.Create(x.Id, ??? Here the FlavorDto ???));
    }

}
```

How do I use the Flavor mapping profile inside FruitProfile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the FlavorDto from your Factory Method and instead use ForMember to Map the FlavorDto to the FruitDto?

```
 public class FruitDto
 {
    protected FruitDto() { }
    public static FruitDto Create(int Id)
    {
        // ..
        return fruit;
    }

    public FlavorDto Flavor { get; set; }
 }
```

```
public class FruitProfile : Profile 
{
    public FruitProfile ()
    {
        CreateMap<FruitEntity, FruitDto>()
            .ConstructUsing(x => FruitDto.Create(x.Id))
            .ForMember(d => d.Flavor, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => 
            // Where ever you fetch your FlavorEntity from, for ex.
            s.Flavor
            // Or, if you have a factory method for your flavor too
            FlavorDto.Create(s.FlavorId)
));
    }

}
```